# Telegraf unsupported type problem when using inputs.tail with data format csv

Tags: csv, influxdb, telegraf

I’m trying to get CSV data into InfluxDB using Telegraf and inputs.tail. For several applications it works but for one I get “unsupported type”. Anybody knows how to find out the details? Debug doesn’t say much. It might possibly have to do with the timestamp format. Timestamp can be for instance 20200601070000 so in `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf` I configured

`csv_timestamp_format = “20060102150405”`

Is this a valid format? I have tried putting it in the Go "reference time".

Example from log file:

`2020-06-01T07:30:00Z E! [inputs.tail] Malformed log line in “/var/log/metrics.csv”: [“20200601071500,app_01,900,f,6,0,2,0,4,4,0,2,0,0,2,2,2,170,1010,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,15,18,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.011111111,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0”]: unsupported type`

Excerpt from `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf`:

```
csv_column_types = [“int”,“string”,“int”,“string”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”,“float”]
csv_timestamp_column = “timestamp”
csv_timestamp_format = “20060102150405”
```

Best regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

The column type for timestamp should have been "string". After changing from "int" to "string" the data was read into InfluxDB without "unsupported type" error.